# Set JLabel in Tab of JTabbedPane (JAVA)

Tags: java, swing, tabs, jlabel, jtabbedpane

I am trying to put a JLabel in tab of JTabbedPane but it isn't showing... here is the code that i am using:

```
...
public class FormulariosTabbedPane extends JTabbedPane implements IEventoListener<TipoDeEvento> {

...
    @Override
    public void eventoDisparado(EventoGenerado<TipoDeEvento> eventoGenerado) {
        ...

        addTab(null, pnlCrearEditarProceso);

        JLabel labelPest = new JLabel("Crear proceso");
        labelPest.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 0, 5));
        labelPest.setForeground(Color.WHITE);

        setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(pnlCrearEditarProceso), labelPest);
        setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(pnlCrearEditarProceso), new ButtonTabPanel(this));
        setSelectedIndex(indexOfComponent(pnlCrearEditarProceso));

        ...
    }
...

}
```

And here the result:

[image]

What can be wrong?... thanks in advance

Comment: Rather than animated images of your IDE and uncompilable code snippets..  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be caused because of this:

```
setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(pnlCrearEditarProceso),labelPest);
setTabComponentAt(indexOfComponent(pnlCrearEditarProceso),new ButtonTabPanel(this));
```

This won't merge the `labelPest` and `ButtonTabPanel` together, this firstly use labelPest, but then ButtonTabPanel overwrites labelPest.
Your ButtonTabPanel should contain a Label, then this will work. Without the source code of this class I cant help you in general.

Comment: ooooh yeaahh... thanks..!!! that was my wrong in ButtonTabPanel i added the label and it's work perfectly...